# MV Cox model with $R^2$ for each covariate

Tags: cox-model, r-squared

I found a paper with MV Cox regression results. The authors show an $R^2$ result for each covariate included in the model. How did they do that? I supposed that $R^2$ was calculated only for the entire model.

Variable    n

```
            /N (%)      HR(95% CI)          P-value         R-squared

Cov1        50/336(15%) 3.91(2.70, 5.66)    P-val: <.001    R2 = 20.7%

Cov2        82/240(34%) 0.41(0.27, 0.63)    P-val: <.001    R2 = 34.2%

Cov3        96/254(38%) 0.41(0.28, 0.62)    P-val: <.001    R2 = 34.2%
```

Answer (score 2):

It is possible to compute partial R2 coefficients for Cox regression models which include multiple predictor variables. For example, the slides available here provide such an example (see slide 29):

http://citeseerx.ist.psu.edu/viewdoc/download?doi=10.1.1.437.703&rep=rep1&type=pdf

As for how the authors did that, it's best if you reach out to them directly and seek clarification on how exactly they computed their partial R2 coefficients.  Alternatively, you can try to include information about the paper in your question, in case someone who is familiar with the paper may shed light on the matter.